# After upgrading to Tailwindcss 2.1 with JIT mode using laravel-mix and sass, tailwind modules are not being imported

Tags: laravel, sass, tailwind-css, laravel-mix

I've upgraded to TailwindCss 2.1 and added mode: 'jit' to tailwind.config.js.
When I run `yarn run dev`, only tailwindcss/base is imported into the compiled app.css file.

tailwind.css:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
/* end base */
@import "tailwindcss/components";
/* end comps */
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
/* end utils */
```

app.scss:

```
 @import "../css/tailwind.css";
 /* start of custom css */
```

webpack.mix.js:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
 const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
 
 mix.sass('resources/scss/app.scss', 'public/css')
.options({
    processCssUrls: false,
    postCss: [
        tailwindcss('tailwind.config.js')
    ]
});
```

I originally had the imports in with the app.scss file but moved them to see if that helped.  Anyone have any ideas why "tailwindcss/components" and  "tailwindcss/utilities" won't import?  "tailwindcss/base" imports as well as other scss files that are being imported in app.scss

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the pathing was incorrect in the purge section of tailwind.config.js:

- original:

> ```
>     purge: [
>         './../resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
>         './../vendor/livewire/livewire/src/**/*.blade.php',
>         './public/**/*.html',
>         './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}',
>     ],
> ```

- correct:

> ```
>     purge: [
>         './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
>         './vendor/livewire/livewire/src/**/*.blade.php',
>         './public/**/*.html',
>         './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}',
>     ],
> ```